# What are the two prohibitions, and why thank God after being bound by them?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It's well known that there are [four main categories of persons](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%90) who offer a *korban toda* (or say *hagomel*) to thank God, one of which is מי שהיה חבוש בב׳ האיסורים, someone who was bound by the two prohibitions.

What are the two prohibitions, and why does someone who was bound by them thank God?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 6):

That a person was able to get out of attending a company "holiday party" in December. He avoided avodas zarah and performing ad delo yada several months early.

Answer (score 4):

It is birchat ha gAmal -- which reminds us of the 2 issurim related to camels. They are not kosher, so we are forbidden to eat or derive pleasure from.

Comment: Danno ur wrong about not deriving benefit or pleasure, camels aren't an issues of בשר וחלב, just treif

Comment: oh no. my answer to a Purim Torah question was not perfectly in line with halacha? Whatever shall I do?

Comment: Purim Torah is one thing, but apikorsis is never ok

Comment: Uh oh, then don't read my blog.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading it wrong: it's not בב׳ האיסורים, *by the two prohibitions*, but בבית האסורים, *in jail*. And the reason someone who was חבוש there needs to thank God is that חבוש כמבושל.